# What is the alternative to entrySet of map and the use of stream in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have constructed a `HashMap` which contains a mapping of field name to value. The mapping will be used to construct a url query string.

Here is my code:

```
val map = HashMap<String, Any>();
// Build the map
return map.entrySet().stream()
        .map { p -> urlEncodeUTF8(p.getKey()) + "=" + urlEncodeUTF8(p.getValue()) }
        .reduce { p1, p2 -> p1.toString() + "&" + p2 }
        .orElse("")
```

However kotlin does not like the function `entrySet()`.

It complaints about `Cannot access 'entrySet': it is package-private in 'HashMap'`.

`forEach` is not the right answer for me because I want to use the `stream` syntax to reduce the results to a single string.

I have tried `createEntrySet` and `entries` but neither of them supports stream.

Comment: Doesn't this work?  val newMap =  map.entries.stream() ...

Comment: Now I tried it again, it works. But while I were posting the question, my intellij ide flags `entries`. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  return map.entries.stream()
        .map { "${urlEncodeUTF8(it.key)}=${urlEncodeUTF8(it.value)}" }
        .reduce { p1, p2 -> "$p1&$p2" }
        .orElse("")
```